# Magento Coupon code issue on Cart Page

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have strange issue on Magento Cart Page.

When I try to add coupon code on cart page that is not applying.
But If I add that (on cart page) after login to front end user account then it worked perfectly.

And Another method that coupon code accepting,
After adding product to cart and go to further (Proceed to checkout) and came to cart page.
On this occasion that coupon code worked perfectly (Even not Front end user login)

So could you please help me for solve this issue.

Comment: Please first off check your promotional rules for coupons. I think u have applied for not-logged user also.

Comment: I need "not-logged user" to apply that coupon also